# Error code 1 when installing kivy on MAC

Tags: python, kivy, atom-editor

I think I must have deleted some very important files on my computer by accident but I uninstalled everything and re-installed them and I am trying to run kivy on atom but this error keeps showing up no matter what.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Headers/LaunchServices.h:43:10: fatal error: 
      'LaunchServices/UTCoreTypes.h' file not found
#include <LaunchServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

someone please help

Comment: Would it work to just copy it in? https://github.com/chrisjenx/wakemesleepme/blob/master/OSX/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Headers/LaunchServices.h

Comment: You can't just check to see if the file exists in that folder?

Comment: they said that I am not a member of the group "wheel". Should I go ahead and unlock and replace the file with the git hub link that you sent over?

Comment: I dont know if it will work. But backup your old one, and try. I suppose that wouldnt hurt.